# react native android studio emulator cmd m debugger short cut is not working

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

in mac react native android studio emulator cmd m short cut is not opening debugger

i did key map change mac, visual studio

but it is not working

how can i do

open android emulator debugger memu using short cut

please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.